# How to handle the drag,zoom functionality individually for circle,image,line etc drawn on canvas in android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I used the canvas to draw the things on it but never handled the drag and zoom functionality of each things drawn on canvas. Has anyone handled this type of scenario?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most efficient way, but I would start with the following approach:

1. When starting a shape drawing, create a new SurfaceView and draw upon here
2. Whilst drawing, keep track of the min and max boundaries of the shape
3. When ending the shape drawing, clip the view to the boundaries
4. Attach the appropriate listeners to the view for drag, zoom, etc.

If the SurfaceView background is transparent the views should be draggable over one another. You might get conflicts on which view you grab and drag when they overlap though.

Comment: thank you for the flow to start with surfaceview could you provide some good links relate to surfaceview drawing handling.

Answer (score 0):

For touches you just need to find a way of deciding which element you've selected when you touch the screen. For that you can get the bounds of the objects and decide which you touched.

Then when you detect the touch position moving, if the initial touch selected an object, you should change the object's position by the offset in pixels that the touch has moved to "drag" the object on the canvas.

I haven't ever implemented zoom myself but I'm sure it starts off the same - having to detect which object you select. Then you may be able to use a pinch scale listener on the canvas or something.

Hey! I found some Google [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html) on how to do exactly what you want actually!

Comment: colud you please more elaborate on this topic because i could not be able to get that how to map the touch points when draging exactly to the particular object when multiple objects drawn on canvas.